# Loop Background Image Animation in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am new to Canvas and want to loop background Image in the below smoke effect. On searching, I have found an example that how we can loop background Image in canvas [Link to looping animation](http://bdadam.com/samples/canvas-background-scrolling.html) so I tried integrating the looping code with the smoke effect but no success. Any help will be appreciated.

```js
     // Create an array to store our particles
     var particles = [];
     // The amount of particles to render
     var particleCount = 60;
     // The maximum velocity in each direction
     var maxVelocity = 2;
     // The target frames per second (how often do we want to update / redraw the scene)
     var targetFPS = 33;
     // Set the dimensions of the canvas as variables so they can be used.
     var canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
     var canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;
     // borders for particles on top and bottom
     var borderTop = 0.01 * canvasHeight;
     var borderBottom = 0.99 * canvasHeight;
     // Create an image object (only need one instance)
     var imageObj = new Image();

     var looping = false;
     var totalSeconds = 0;
     // Once the image has been downloaded then set the image on all of the particles
     imageObj.onload = function() {
       particles.forEach(function(particle) {
         particle.setImage(imageObj);
       });
     };
     // Once the callback is arranged then set the source of the image
     imageObj.src = "https://image.ibb.co/fdpeJF/Smoke.png";
     // A function to create a particle object.
     function Particle(context) {
       // Set the initial x and y positions
       this.x = 0;
       this.y = 0;
       // Set the initial velocity
       this.xVelocity = 0;
       this.yVelocity = 0;
       // Set the radius
       this.radius = 5;
       // Store the context which will be used to draw the particle
       this.context = context;
       // The function to draw the particle on the canvas.
       this.draw = function() {
         // If an image is set draw it
         if (this.image) {
           this.context.drawImage(this.image, this.x - 128, this.y - 128);
           // If the image is being rendered do not draw the circle so break out of the draw function
           return;
         }
         // Draw the circle as before, with the addition of using the position and the radius from this object.
         this.context.beginPath();
         this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
         this.context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)";
         this.context.fill();
         this.context.closePath();
       };
       // Update the particle.
       this.update = function() {
         // Update the position of the particle with the addition of the velocity.
         this.x += this.xVelocity;
         this.y += this.yVelocity;
         // Check if has crossed the right edge
         if (this.x >= canvasWidth) {
           this.xVelocity = -this.xVelocity;
           this.x = canvasWidth;
         }
         // Check if has crossed the left edge
         else if (this.x <= 0) {
           this.xVelocity = -this.xVelocity;
           this.x = 0;
         }
         // Check if has crossed the bottom edge
         if (this.y >= borderBottom) {
           this.yVelocity = -this.yVelocity;
           this.y = borderBottom;
         }
         // Check if has crossed the top edge
         else if (this.y <= borderTop) {
           this.yVelocity = -this.yVelocity;
           this.y = borderTop;
         }
       };
       // A function to set the position of the particle.
       this.setPosition = function(x, y) {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
       };
       // Function to set the velocity.
       this.setVelocity = function(x, y) {
         this.xVelocity = x;
         this.yVelocity = y;
       };
       this.setImage = function(image) {
         this.image = image;
       };
     }
     // A function to generate a random number between 2 values
     function generateRandom(min, max) {
       return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
     }
     // The canvas context if it is defined.
     var context;
     // Initialise the scene and set the context if possible
     function init() {
       var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
       canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
       canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
       if (canvas.getContext) {
         // Set the context variable so it can be re-used
         context = canvas.getContext('2d');
         // Create the particles and set their initial positions and velocities
         for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; ++i) {
           var particle = new Particle(context);
           // Set the position to be inside the canvas bounds
           particle.setPosition(generateRandom(0, canvasWidth), generateRandom(borderTop, borderBottom));
           // Set the initial velocity to be either random and either negative or positive
           particle.setVelocity(generateRandom(-maxVelocity, maxVelocity), generateRandom(-maxVelocity, maxVelocity));
           particles.push(particle);
           context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 
         }
       } else {
         alert("Please use a modern browser");
       }
     }
     // The function to draw the scene
     function draw() {
       //  background image
       context.globalAlpha = 1;
             context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
       context.drawImage(backImg, 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
       context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255, .5)";
       context.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

       context.globalAlpha = 0.75;
        context.globalCompositeOperation = 'soft-lights';
       // Fog layer
       // Go through all of the particles and draw them.
       particles.forEach(function(particle) {
         particle.draw();
       });

     }
     // Update the scene
     function update() {
       particles.forEach(function(particle) {
         particle.update();
       });
     }
     // Initialize the scene
     init();
     backImg = new Image();
      backImg.src = 'https://image.ibb.co/cTOOdF/e2VZQY.jpg';
       // If the context is set then we can draw the scene (if not then the browser does not support canvas)
       if (context) {
         setInterval(function() {
           // Update the scene befoe drawing
           update();
           // Draw the scene
           draw();
         }, 1000 / targetFPS);
       }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" ></canvas>
```

Comment: This is a neat animation. Nice job so far

Comment: The flickering in the answer given is caused when using `setInterval` to time the animations. Look up `requestAnimationFrame` not `setInterval` to get the best possible results

Comment: Thanks @Blindman, I tried replacing setInterval to requestAnimationFrame and I think it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added a few lines. Hopefully you can spot them. I commented everything I added.

```js
// Create an array to store our particles
var particles = [];
// The amount of particles to render
var particleCount = 60;
// The maximum velocity in each direction
var maxVelocity = 2;
// The target frames per second (how often do we want to update / redraw the scene)
var targetFPS = 33;
// Set the dimensions of the canvas as variables so they can be used.
var canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
var canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;
// borders for particles on top and bottom
var borderTop = 0.01 * canvasHeight;
var borderBottom = 0.99 * canvasHeight;
// Create an image object (only need one instance)
var imageObj = new Image();
// x position of scrolling image
var imageX = 0;

var looping = false;
var totalSeconds = 0;
// Once the image has been downloaded then set the image on all of the particles
imageObj.onload = function() {
  particles.forEach(function(particle) {
    particle.setImage(imageObj);
  });
};
// Once the callback is arranged then set the source of the image
imageObj.src = "https://image.ibb.co/fdpeJF/Smoke.png";
// A function to create a particle object.
function Particle(context) {
  // Set the initial x and y positions
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  // Set the initial velocity
  this.xVelocity = 0;
  this.yVelocity = 0;
  // Set the radius
  this.radius = 5;
  // Store the context which will be used to draw the particle
  this.context = context;
  // The function to draw the particle on the canvas.
  this.draw = function() {
    // If an image is set draw it
    if (this.image) {
      this.context.drawImage(this.image, this.x - 128, this.y - 128);
      // If the image is being rendered do not draw the circle so break out of the draw function
      return;
    }
    // Draw the circle as before, with the addition of using the position and the radius from this object.
    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    this.context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)";
    this.context.fill();
    this.context.closePath();
  };
  // Update the particle.
  this.update = function() {
    // Update the position of the particle with the addition of the velocity.
    this.x += this.xVelocity;
    this.y += this.yVelocity;
    // Check if has crossed the right edge
    if (this.x >= canvasWidth) {
      this.xVelocity = -this.xVelocity;
      this.x = canvasWidth;
    }
    // Check if has crossed the left edge
    else if (this.x <= 0) {
      this.xVelocity = -this.xVelocity;
      this.x = 0;
    }
    // Check if has crossed the bottom edge
    if (this.y >= borderBottom) {
      this.yVelocity = -this.yVelocity;
      this.y = borderBottom;
    }
    // Check if has crossed the top edge
    else if (this.y <= borderTop) {
      this.yVelocity = -this.yVelocity;
      this.y = borderTop;
    }
  };
  // A function to set the position of the particle.
  this.setPosition = function(x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  };
  // Function to set the velocity.
  this.setVelocity = function(x, y) {
    this.xVelocity = x;
    this.yVelocity = y;
  };
  this.setImage = function(image) {
    this.image = image;
  };
}
// A function to generate a random number between 2 values
function generateRandom(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
// The canvas context if it is defined.
var context;
// Initialise the scene and set the context if possible
function init() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  if (canvas.getContext) {
    // Set the context variable so it can be re-used
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // Create the particles and set their initial positions and velocities
    for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; ++i) {
      var particle = new Particle(context);
      // Set the position to be inside the canvas bounds
      particle.setPosition(generateRandom(0, canvasWidth), generateRandom(borderTop, borderBottom));
      // Set the initial velocity to be either random and either negative or positive
      particle.setVelocity(generateRandom(-maxVelocity, maxVelocity), generateRandom(-maxVelocity, maxVelocity));
      particles.push(particle);
      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);  
    }
  } else {
    alert("Please use a modern browser");
  }
}
// The function to draw the scene
function draw() {
  //  background image
  context.globalAlpha = 1;
  context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  // draw twice to cover wrap around
  context.drawImage(backImg, imageX, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  context.drawImage(backImg, imageX + canvasWidth, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  context.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255, .5)";
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

  context.globalAlpha = 0.75;
   context.globalCompositeOperation = 'soft-light';
  // Fog layer
  // Go through all of the particles and draw them.
  particles.forEach(function(particle) {
    particle.draw();
  });

}
// Update the scene
function update() {
  // incrementally change image position of background to scroll left
  imageX -= maxVelocity;

  if (imageX < -canvasWidth) {
    imageX += canvasWidth;
  }

  particles.forEach(function(particle) {
    particle.update();
  });
}
// Initialize the scene
init();
backImg = new Image();
backImg.src = 'https://image.ibb.co/cTOOdF/e2VZQY.jpg';
// If the context is set then we can draw the scene (if not then the browser does not support canvas)
if (context) {
  setInterval(function() {
    // Update the scene befoe drawing
    update();
    // Draw the scene
    draw();
  }, 1000 / targetFPS);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks @Patrick, for your answer. But If I make Canvas Full-screen  as already shared in the example, then there is flickering in the Image while moving and I was not able to figure out that how this flickering can be stopped if the Image covers the screen of 1920X 1000 px and also how can I slow down the speed of animation

Comment: @watereffect when you reassign a canvas's width and height, it reinitializes, which clears the painted context. There is nothing to resolve that issue, just note that typically users don't resize windows when browsing nearly as much as developers do while testing.

Comment: I agree with your point but I have screen of resolution 1920X1080 and the Image is flickering while moving. Also, how can I slow down the speed of animation may be it can stop the flickering of Image

Comment: Change the line `imageX -= maxVelocity` to affect the speed of the movement. As for the flickering, I cannot reproduce that on my computer, so I don't know what the problem is there.

Comment: There are a few general tips to improve your code performance, but that is beyond the scope of this question. Please post a new question to address that separately.

Comment: I am Extremely grateful for your help @Patrick, I really appreciate it.Sure, I will update other question for performance

Comment: When doing any form of animation please use `requestAnimationFrame` (rAF). The flickering the OP noted is the result of incorrectly calling the rendering function via `setInterval` causing the canvas back buffer to be dumped to the display RAM immediately on exiting the function. rAF defers all visual changes made in the function till the vertical refresh, this eliminates shearing and flickering

Comment: @Blindman67 While I agree, that also removes the ability to set your own framerate via adjustable timeout value, and making that change affects a lot of the speed-based components of this program, which is beyond the scope of this particular question and would take much more effort to address, which is why I suggested an additional question be asked to address performance issues

Comment: The browser does not let you set the device frame rate, updating the visuals can be done at 60,30,20,15,10... frames a second by skipping calls .Adjusting speed via out of sync render rates is bad practice and results in poor quality animation.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer given some additional improvements to the code structure.

- Use `requestAnimationFrame` to call render calls.
- Don't expose properties of objects if not needed.
- Don't use `forEach` iteration in time critical code. Use `for` loops.
- Use constants where ever possible.
- Comments that state the obvious are just noise in the source code making it harder to read. Limit comment to abstracts that may not be obvious to another programmer reading the code.

  eg

  `// If an image is set draw it`

  `if (this.image) {`

  Really is that comment of any use to anyone. Comments should help not degrade the readability of code.

Also the original code tried to set the global composite operations to `soft-lights` this is not a know operation. I corrected it to `soft-light` which can on some machines, be a very slow render operation. It may pay to selected another operation for machines that are slow. This can be done by simply monitoring the render time of particles and switching operation type is too slow.

A quick rewrite of the OP's code.

```js
const particles = [];
     const particleCount = 60;
     const maxVelocity = 2;
     var canvasWidth = innerWidth;
     var canvasHeight = innerHeight;
     var borderTop = 0.01 * canvasHeight;
     var borderBottom = 0.99 * canvasHeight;
     var ctx;
     const backgroundColor = "rgba(255,255,255, .5)";
     const backgroundSpeed = -0.1;
     var looping = false;
     var totalSeconds = 0;
     var lastTime = 0;
     var frameTime = (1000 / 30) - (1000 / 120); // one quater frame short to 
                                                 // allow for timing error
     var imageCount = 0;
     const backImg = new Image();
     const imageObj = new Image();     
     backImg.src = 'https://image.ibb.co/cTOOdF/e2VZQY.jpg';
     imageObj.src = "https://image.ibb.co/fdpeJF/Smoke.png";
     backImg.onload = imageObj.onload = imageLoad;
     function imageLoad(){
         imageCount += 1;
         if(imageCount === 2){
             init();
         }
     }
     function init() {
         var canvas = myCanvas;
         canvas.width = innerWidth;
         canvas.height = innerHeight;

         ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
         for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; i += 1) {
             particles.push(new Particle(ctx));
         }
         lastTime = performance.now();
         requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
     }     
     function mainLoop(time){
         if(time-lastTime > frameTime){
             lastTime = time;
             update();
             draw(time);
         }
         requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
     }
     const rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;  // names are best short (short only without ambiguity)
     function Particle(ctx) { 
         var x, y, xVel, yVel, radius, image;
         const color = "rgba(0, 255, 255, 1)";
         x = rand(0, canvasWidth), 
         y = rand(borderTop, borderBottom);
         xVel = rand(-maxVelocity, maxVelocity);
         yVel = rand(-maxVelocity, maxVelocity);
         radius = 5;
         image = imageObj;
         this.draw = function () { ctx.drawImage(image, x - 128, y - 128) }
         this.update = function () {
             x += xVel;
             y += yVel;
             if (x >= canvasWidth) {
                 xVel = -xVel;
                 x = canvasWidth;
             }
             else if (x <= 0) {
                 xVel = -xVel;
                 x = 0;
             }
             if (y >= borderBottom) {
                 yVel = -yVel;
                 y = borderBottom;
             }
             else if (y <= borderTop) {
                 yVel = -yVel;
                 y = borderTop;
             }
         }
     }


     function draw(time) {
         var i,x;
         ctx.globalAlpha = 1;
         ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
         x = time * backgroundSpeed;
         x = ((x % canvasWidth) + canvasWidth) % canvasWidth;
         ctx.drawImage(backImg, x, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
         ctx.drawImage(backImg, x - canvasWidth, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
         ctx.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
         ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

         ctx.globalAlpha = 0.75;
         ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'soft-light';
         for(i = 0; i < particles.length; i += 1){
             particles[i].draw();
         }
     }
     function update() {
         for(i = 0; i < particles.length; i += 1){
             particles[i].update();
         }
     }
```

```css
canvas {
   position : absolute;
   top : 0px;
   left : 0px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id=myCanvas></canvas>
```

Comment: @BlindMand, Agree with all your points and will take care while posting questions. I am beginner in Canvas and don't have much knowledge of it. Unfortunately, there is still flickering while repeating the Image. You can check at the point where the Image repeats, there is some sort of flickering while moving and If I slow down the speed and Use HD Image, the flickering is more noticeable and this is the problem I am still facing.

Comment: @watereffect I would say that the flicker is the result of frames being dropped. This happens when the time to render a frame is  close and over 1/60th of a second. You will get an improved render speed if you change `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'soft-light';` to `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';` and reduce the alpha a little `"ctx.globalAlpha = 0.7;"` to sort of make a similar FX.  "lighter" and "screen" are two other filters that are as fast as "source-over" and with different smoke images you can get the same FX (v close) to the result of "soft-light"

Comment: Changing the globalAlpha value solved my Problem. Thank you very much for your help and detailed explanation